# Ninject how to prevent shared objects

Tags: ninject

I have a binding like the following in my kernel

```
kernel.Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependencyImplementation>();
```

In a single app domain, we multiple calls to `kernel.Get<IMyDependency>()` are made, does `Get<>` returns a shared instance or a new every time?

We discovered a thread-safety issue in one of our dependencies that teams are working on rectifying, but in the interim if we can get ninject to distribute one separate object (not shared) per Get<> call, it could save the day for us.

Is there any way in Ninject to say for one particular dependency to return a new instance (or at least a non-shared one) with every Get<> Call?

Answer (score 1):

> does `Get<IMyDependency>` returns a shared instance or a new every time?

You get a new instance of `MyDependencyImplementation` on each call. This is the default behaviour unless the call to `Bind()` has been made with a specific scope.

You may have a look at the [Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) documentation.